# change action for form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

how to change action of form using javascript and using onsubmit button .  i tried to write this but nothing happen and page wont change although i change the action form using js in jsp file
is there way to debug js

How do I change a form's action attribute right after clicking the submit button?

```html
<form id="cust" name="cust" method="post" onsubmit="return myAction()">
  <table style="with: 50%">
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td><input type="date" name="departureDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>
        <select name="comeFrom">
          <option value="a">a</option>
          <option value="b">b</option>
          <option value="c">c</option>
          <option value="d">d</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" name="io" value="next" />
</form>
```

Comment: If you submit your form, the page is reloaded and everything reset - since you return true on the submit, the form is submitted

Comment: Also you use getElementById but the form has no ID. Change `name="cust"` to `id="cust"` but it will still submit

Comment: WHY do you want to change the action? If you want to submit to the server and not reload the form, you need to look into AJAX

Comment: @mplungjan yes i set the id too and the action wont change

Comment: it changes but then your form is submitted and since you do not HAVE an action, the page just reloads, clearing the changed action

Comment: @mplungjan yes i can use action in form ,but i need to change the action using js , therefore is there a way to submit form and change the action using js

Comment: Also do NOT call your function action!!!

Comment: Yes, AJAX the form, then change the action - but you do not tell me WHY you want to change the action

Comment: I made you a snippet and changed the name of the action to myAction - now it runs but will not KEEP the action since the page is reloaded. You can see in the console

Comment: @mplungjan yes its run what is the different?

Comment: I changed the name of the function which is reserved

Comment: @mplungjan thankyou i would like to know what tool do you use for debug  piece of code in browser?

Comment: Jsfiddle or the stacksnippets here plus chrome devtools (press f12)

Answer (score 1):

This is as simple as it can get. Listen for the submit event and in the callback function change the action.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.target.action = 'page02';
});
```

```html
<form name="form01" action="page01" method="post">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```